# 3rd Highest Salary in the Employees Table

Tags: sql

Is it the right query to return the 3rd Highest Salary in the Employees Table?

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE emp_no in (SELECT emp_no FROM employees ORDER BY salary DESC FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY)
ORDER BY salary ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: use Limit `SELECT * FROM `employees` ORDER BY salary ASC LIMIT 3, 1;`

Comment: Define "the third highest salary" properly first. (What about duplicates?) Then tell us which RDBMS you actually use: MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I use Oracle SQL

Answer (score 1):

I would use a window function in order to be able to deal with duplicate values:

```
select *
from (
  select *, 
         dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as rnk
  from employees
) t
where rnk = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM  employees ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
```

Query orders employees by salary and returns one result which from third row in result set. I think this will work for MySQL and PostgreSQL.